# If Statement when x is near a value

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, floating-point

I am trying to solve the numerical equation:

sin^2(x)tan(x) = 0.499999

Using a while loop in C.
However I was only able to get program to print an answer if I rounded to 0.5. This led me to thinking, is there a way of writing:

```
For(x=0;x<=360;x=x+0.001)
{ y=f(x)
If(y **is near x**(e.g. Within 1 percent) )
Do something etc.
}
```

Is there a way of telling the computer to execute a task if the value is sufficiently near. Such as in this if statement?
Thank you.

Comment: Google *epsilon* in the context. For example, `if(fabs(x - y) < EPSILON) { ... }`

Comment: Near could means that given some e, |y-x|<e then you have your condition, or that 1-e<|y/x|<1+e, or...

Comment: @WeatherVane: If `x` is 0.0002 and y is 0.0001, your test is true but the difference is 50%, not 1% as requested in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's true, my comment was not an answer but a suggested avenue of approach, an *absolute* approach, not a *proportional* one as in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a relative difference, such as:

```
#include <math.h>

static inline double reldiff(double x, double y)
{
    return fabs(x - y) / fmax(fabs(x), fabs(y));
}
```

Now your test becomes:

```
if (reldiff(x, y) < 0.01)   // 1% as requested
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple solution would be.

```
if (y >= x-x/100 && y <= x+x/100)
{
   [execute code...]
}
```

Essentially what it does is check if `y` is between [x minus 1% of `x`] and [x plus 1% of `x`]. Should work alright.